# Assemble and analyze a list of lists from dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've got a .csv file that looks a bit like this:

```
COL_A    COL_B                   COL_C
1        2020-05-26T00:01:01     99999
2        2020-05-26T00:01:02     99999
3        2020-05-26T00:01:03     99999
4        2020-05-26T00:01:04     2.3
5        2020-05-26T00:01:05     2.3
6        2020-05-26T00:01:06     2.3
7        2020-05-26T00:01:07     99999
8        2020-05-26T00:01:08     99999
9        2020-05-26T00:01:09     3.4
10       2020-05-26T00:01:10     3.4
11       2020-05-26T00:01:11     99999
12       2020-05-26T00:01:12     99999
```

I'd like to be able to identify the longest continuous span of rows where `COL_C` is `< 5` and return that list of rows.  The desired output would be something like:

```
[
    [4        2020-05-26T00:01:04     2.3,
     5        2020-05-26T00:01:05     2.3,
     6        2020-05-26T00:01:06     2.3]
], 3
```

The way I have approached this in theory is building a list of lists that meet the criteria, and then using `max` over the lists with `len` as the key.  I've attempted this:

```
import pandas as pd

def max_c(csv_file):
    row_list = []
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        while row[2] < 5:
            span = [*row]
            row_list.append(span)
    return max(row_list, key=len)
```

I know enough to know that this isn't correct syntax for what I'm trying to do and I can even explain why, but do not know enough to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use `cumsum()` to identify blocks and do a groupby:

```
s = df['COL_C'].lt(5)
sizes = s.groupby([s,(~s).cumsum()]).transform('size') * s

# max block 1 size
# max_size == 0 means all values are >= 5
max_size = sizes.max()


df[sizes==max_size]
```

Output:

```
   COL_A                COL_B  COL_C
3      4  2020-05-26T00:01:04    2.3
4      5  2020-05-26T00:01:05    2.3
5      6  2020-05-26T00:01:06    2.3
```

**Details:**

`s` is:

```
0     False
1     False
2     False
3      True
4      True
5      True
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10    False
11    False
Name: COL_C, dtype: bool
```

if we just do `s.cumsum()` then the `True` obviously belong to different groups. Instead we do `(~s).cumsum()` we get:

```
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     3
4     3
5     3
6     4
7     5
8     5
9     5
10    6
11    7
Name: COL_C, dtype: int64
```

Almost there, but each group of `True` is now preceded by a row of `False`. That suggests we group by both `s` and the negated cumsum.

Comment: This works, can you please explain what is happening in the groupby function?  I can understand everything else, but I am not clear on `([s, (~s).cumsum()])`.  Why are you summing a boolean reverse of `s`?  Thanks for any help

Comment: @auslander see added details.

Comment: I am kind of dense I guess, and still don't understand... the point is just to count up the largest unbroken sequence of "True" so I would assume True should belong to different groups. I am very thankful for your time though and will keep trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Quang ,find the greater than 5 and create the sub-group, then we just filter out he value more than 5, and get the group with `transform` `count`. pick the `max` count `index`

```
s=df.COL_C.ge(5)
s=df.loc[~s,'COL_A'].groupby(s.cumsum()).transform('count')
target=df.loc[s[s==s.max()].index]
Out[299]: 
   COL_A                COL_B  COL_C
3      4  2020-05-26T00:01:04    2.3
4      5  2020-05-26T00:01:05    2.3
5      6  2020-05-26T00:01:06    2.3
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and both ran at effectively 0 seconds against ~60K rows, I would mark both yours and Quang's answers correct if I could as they both teach some really helpful nuances of pandas.  Thank you.